# Corrupted/Missing DLLs on Windows 8.1 installation

Tags: windows, windows-8, dll, dism

I recently purchased a second-hand laptop, which I am experiencing some problems with.  During my initial scan, everything seemed great, but upon bringing it home to install some of my commonly used programs, I received multiple errors.

When trying to run an ASCII based game, I encounter the error "The program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer..."

Similarly, when running a different program, it encounters the error "The program can't start because d3dx9_38.dll is missing from your computer..."

Now, having some experience in the field, I have tried running "sfc /scannow" but it said that no errors were found.

I am currently running "dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth", but it has been running for about 45 minutes and is still on 20%.

If this last option does not work, where should I go from here?  Would a clean install be the best option?  If so, can I reinstall Windows without the media?

Comment: MSVCR100.dll is part of an optional installation, have you installed that installation, based on your error you have not.  Install the appropriate version of the c++ redistributable 2010 to fix that error.  Your other error is because you don't have DX 9 installed, you should install it, to resolve that error.  If SFC found no errors, then installing or running the DISM command, won't solve your problem.  Your Windows installation isn't corrupt your just missing required components for the applications your attempting to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MSVCR100.dll` is part of the Visual C++ 2010 Runtime ([32Bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=8328), [64Bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13523)). Download the required runtime and install it.

The `d3dx9_38.dll` is part of the [DirectX 9 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=34429).Install it, to fix the issue.